# Prime and maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I tell that the ideal $(X-Y,Y^2-Y)$ is prime or maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$? I've shown that the problem can be reduced to considering the ideal (X-Y), due to the theorems of isomorphism. But I can't find a clue in this case or a general method while working with multi-variable polynomials, I know I should study the quotient, but where do I evaluate it?

Comment: I don't follow how it "can be reduced to considering the ideal $(X-Y)$".  Would you explain your thinking on that?

Comment: @hardmath $Y^2-Y+Y(X-Y)=YX-Y$, then $YX-Y-Y^2+Y=YX-Y^2=Y(X-Y)$ which is in the ideal $(X-Y)$ The third theorem of isomorphism does the rest (Y/J=(Y/I)/(J/I). Am I wrong?

Comment: I suspect you've confused what you've really reduced the problem to, in that $(X-Y)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, but $(Y^2 - Y)$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[Y]$.  @MichaelJoyce pretty much pulls the threads together for you to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started.  Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
\varphi: \mathbb{Q}[X,Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y^2 - Y)
$$
given by $\varphi(X) = \varphi(Y) = Y$.  The idea behind constructing this homomorphism is that $X - Y$ being in your ideal morally allows you to identify $X$ and $Y$ in your quotient ring.  This homomorphism is accomplishing that task.  What is the image of this homomorphism?  What is its kernel?

Then, you need to determine if $\mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y^2 - Y)$ is an integral domain, and if so, if it is a field.  How does the factorization $Y^2 - Y = Y(Y-1)$ help you answer these questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ y(y\!-\!1) \in I = (x-y, y(y\!-\!1))$ but $\,y,y\!-\!1\not\in I,\,$ so $I$ is not prime, so not maximal, via

$\qquad\ \ \ \ y\  \in I\, \Rightarrow\ \ \  \  \ \ y = (x-y) f + y(y-1) g\ \Rightarrow\ 1 = 0\ $ for $\, x = 1 = y$

$\qquad y\!-\!1 \in I\, \Rightarrow\ y\!-\!1 = (x-y) f + y(y-1) g\ \Rightarrow\ 1 = 0\ $ for $\, x = 0 = y$